# How to use a value from SELECT in UPDATE statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

below is what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to retrieve an integer value using a `SELECT` statement which I will inturn pass into the `UPDATE` statement, but I have not been sucessful with it. Below is what I have done so far and it doesn't work. Please any suggestion will be highly appreciated. the `$empID` is passed from a form using php.

```
$getemID ="SELECT  `addressID` FROM  `address` WHERE  `userID` =$empID";
$myemID = mysql_query($getemID) or die(mysql_error());
$addrID = $myemID["addressID"];

$sql4="UPDATE `address` 
SET `line1`='$line1', `line2`='$line2', `city`='$city', `zip`='$zip'
WHERE `addressID`=$addrID";
$res = mysql_query($sql4) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Why don't you want to use the where clause to get it done in just one query? `UPDATE address SET ... WHERE userID = <your value>`? But you really should move to PDO or MySQLi and use prepared statements with placeholders instead.

Answer (score 0):

While you should not use the **deprecated** `mysql_*` functions, the following still stands:

The return value of the `mysql_query` call is not an array, but a resource. Use this resource in a call like `mysql_fetch_array` to get the data. Then you can use that data for the other query.

Answer (score 0):

After select query you have to fetch them using mysql_fetch_array. As given below:

```
$getemID ="SELECT  `addressID` FROM  `address` WHERE  `userID` =$empID";
$myemID = mysql_query($getemID) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($myemID);
$addrID = $row["addressID"];
$sql4="UPDATE `address` 
SET `line1`='$line1', `line2`='$line2', `city`='$city', `zip`='$zip'
WHERE `addressID`='$addrID' ";
$res = mysql_query($sql4) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it in a single query like below

```
UPDATE `address` 
SET `line1`='$line1', `line2`='$line2', `city`='$city', `zip`='$zip'
WHERE `addressID` IN (
SELECT  `addressID` FROM  `address` WHERE  `userID` =$empID
)
```